# BIT_COUNT in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'd like to represent the following query in SQLAlchemy:

```
select * from table where bit_count(column & bitmask) > 5
```

Basically I'm looking to select any row with a certain count of flags set.  However, SQLAlchemy doesn't seem to have defined the [BIT_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#function_bit-count) function.  Anyone know any tricks to make this query in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> session.query("id", "name", "thenumber12").\
...         from_statement("SELECT id, name, 12 as "
...                 "thenumber12 FROM users where bit_count(column&bitmask)<:the_val").\
...                 params(the_val=5).all()
```

something like that I imagine...

or

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
>>> engine.execute("select * from table where bit_count(column & bitmask) > 5").scalar()
```

keep in mind im operating under the assumption that this is the correct use of bit_count ...

Comment: Thanks, that first form is what I ended up using.  It seems to take advantage of SQLAlchemy the most.